# ManyToManyField or ForeignKeys in an intermediary model?

Tags: django

I don't understand why should I use ManyToManyField if I will (or might) store extra information along the many-to-many relationships.

The [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) shows this example:

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="membership_invites",
    )
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Why even having the members field there, if the developer already defines the relationship model and also defines the ForeignKeys? :D Why not leaving out the members ManyToManyField ?? What is the benefit? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why should I use `ManyToManyField` if I will (or might) store extra information along the many-to-many relationships.

You do not *need* to do this. But it makes querying more effective. Indeed, you can now query with:

```
Group.objects.filter(members=some_person)
```

this is shorter and more descriptive than working with:

```
Group.objects.filter(membership__person=some_person)
```

It is thus a "coding shortcut" to go from the `Group` model to the `Person` model and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! So this is all, I get a field with some helpers. But no performance difference?

Comment: @Najib: indeed, it will normally not yield any performance gains. It is more to write a "cleaner" query.

Comment: And just as an experienced Django developer, do you find yourself sometimes not using ManyToManyField when you have many-to-many relationship or do you always use it?

Comment: @Najib: you can also filter the intermediate model, for example `Group.objects.filter(memebers=some_person, membership__invite_reason='some_reason')`.

Comment: Willem thank you I got my answer I think. I understand there is nothing against using ManyToMany so I will use it.